# How to show the information in the same page where I am submitting form in django

Tags: django

I am trying to submit a form and get the result in the same page where I have created the form . But , can't get the values in the same page . But , whenever I am trying to take the value in a different page it's working.

My views.py file :

```
def home(request):
    words = request.GET['text']
    count = len(words.split())
    context = {'count':count}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

My index.html file:

```
<div class="container">
        <h3 style="display:inline-block; text-transform: capitalize; padding-top: 10px; border-bottom: 2px solid #e5e5e5;">Word counting app</h3>
        <h5 style="padding-top: 40px;text-transform: capitalize;">enter your word below to count</h5>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <form method="" action="">
                    <textarea name="text" cols="30" rows="7"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" style="padding: 6px 28px; border: none; background:orange; margin-top: 10px;">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <p>{{count}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is weird. your code looks fine

Answer (score 0):

Add form method 'GET' to your html and remove action attribute. If there are no action provided in the form element, it will be posted to same url as your page.

```
<form method="GET">
```